# GCM and Parse conflict

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I have the below things in the `AndroidManifest`. I need to send push notifications from both my webservice and Parse. The problem is that if I run the app as is below, the pushes from my `WS` (webservice) will go through, but the ones from `Parse` won't.

If I comment out the GCM part, Parse will work.

I've also noticed that in the Parse table, when both are enabled, under the `deviceToken` column, Parse will add a `|ID||1|` prefix to the `deviceToken`. If I comment out the GCM part, Parse won't put that prefix to the `deviceToken`. I'm not sure if that matters ...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I need to support both functionalities, but it seems something conflicts with something else. Any ideas?

If you need more source code, let me know please ...

```
    <!-- ================================= GCM ================================= -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.moc.sif" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".pushnotif.gcm.GCMListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".pushnotif.gcm.GCMInstanceIdListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".pushnotif.gcm.GCMRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <!-- ================================= PARSE ================================= -->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".pushnotif.parse.receivers.ParsePushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.moc.sif" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've fixed it.

The problem was that initializing Parse and afterwards I was calling this method:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_sender_id), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

which apparently made Parse override the `deviceToken` in the table. I was using the above `token` to send to my webservice. What I did to solve it was to comment out the above two lines and use the `deviceToken` generated by Parse instead. So both Parse and my webservice are receiving the same `deviceToken` obtained from the Parse library. And both work now ...

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed by Parse team. In my case unfortunetly the other 3rd library also getting token and there is no way to fix it. Parse also blocks "deviceToken" field so I cant event update it to correct one.